# How can I get Scaled within Inset to overlay Rectangle correctly?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, inset

Consider the following graph:

```
Graph[
    DirectedEdge @@@ {
        {9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20, 21}, {1, 21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}
    },
    VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Small
]
```

[image: Graph]

I would like to overlay a rectangle across the top row of nodes `{8, 1, 20}`. One of the [possible forms of `Inset` is](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

> Inset[obj, pos, opos, size]

which seems like the right one to employ. So, I try:

```
Graph[
    DirectedEdge @@@ {
        {9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20, 21}, {1, 21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}
    },
    VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Small,
    Epilog -> {
        Inset[
            Graphics[{RGBColor[0.25, 0.20, 0.25, 0.05], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}],
            Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{1, 0.2}]
        ]
    }
]
```

where the first `Scaled[{0, 1}]` for `pos` is (at least, intended to be) the top-left corner of the graph, and the second `Scaled[{0, 1}]` for `opos` is the top-left corner of the rectangle. The size `Scaled[{1.0, 0.2}]` is so that the overlay extends from left to right, while covering only a fifth of the height of the entire graph. But the expression does not render what I want:

[image: Graph 2]

I have tried tweaking all of the scaled parameters, without any success. Ideally, I would like the overlay to start a little above, and a little to the left of, the graph, so that the labels are also covered.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** If you have to use `Inset`, you can add the option `AspectRatio -> Full` to `Graphics[...]` in the first argument of `Inset` (so that the the graphics primitives can be stretched based on *size* specified in the fourth argument of `Inset`):

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ {{9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20,  21}, 
   {1, 21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Small, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.05, .15}, Scaled /@ {.05, .1}},
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Graphics[{Opacity[.2, Red], Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> Full], 
    Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{1, 0.2}]]}]
```

[image]

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ {{9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20,  21}, 
   {1, 21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Small, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding",
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.05, .1}, Scaled /@ {.05, .1}},
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Graphics[{Opacity[.2, Red], Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> Full], 
    Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{1, 0.2}]]}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
Graph[RandomGraph[{20, 30}], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
 Epilog -> {Inset[Graphics[{Opacity[.2, Red], Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> Full], 
     Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{1, 0.2}]],
   Inset[Graphics[{Opacity[.2, Green], Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> Full], 
     Scaled[{0, .3}], Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0.2}]]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:** You can use `Rectangle` with `Scaled` coordinates:

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ {{9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20, 21}, 
    {1, 21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Small, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled /@ {.05, .15}, Scaled /@ {.05, .1}},
 Epilog -> {{RGBColor[0.25, 0.20, 0.25, 0.05], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, .8}], Scaled[{1, 1}]], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, .2}], Scaled[{1, .4}]]}}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
Graph[RandomGraph[{20, 30}], VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
 Epilog -> {{RGBColor[0.25, 0.20, 0.25, 0.05], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, .8}], Scaled[{1, 1}]], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, .3}], Scaled[{1, .5}]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! `AspectRatio` and `PlotRangePadding` together did the trick for me. The latter was needed because in my actual graph the vertices are images of molecules.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Show`

```
Show[{Graph[
   DirectedEdge @@@ {{9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20, 21}, {1, 
      21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All], 
  Graphics[{RGBColor[0.25, 0.20, 0.25, 0.05], 
    Rectangle[{-1.2, 4.1}, {1.5, 4.5}]}]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[{Graph[
   DirectedEdge @@@ {{9, 10}, {8, 9}, {1, 9}, {21, 22}, {20, 21}, {1, 
      21}, {23, 24}, {10, 23}, {22, 23}}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   ImageSize -> Small], 
  Graphics[{RGBColor[0.25, 0.20, 0.25, 0.05], 
    Rectangle[{-1.2, 3.1}, {1.5, 4.5}]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the powerful general method of first displaying the frame, and then using the readings to overlay the graphics. This will be very useful in my subsequent work.